# Scrollview issue

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

My view structure is basicly like that

```
 <scrollview> 
    <view>
        <subview>
        </subview>
        ... 18 ..
        <subview>
        </subview>
    </view>
</scrollview>
```

When user scrolls to bottom, i make a http request and acording to that request i create 20 more subviews and put them into to main view.

This has no lag when i test on android, but on ios, while loading new subviews, it disables scrolling and i need to wait about 3-4 seconds until its enabled to scroll.
Also I dont add this new subviews one by one, i create 20 of them and put them in to another temporary view and i add that temporary view to "view".

I thought this may happen because i add so many views, so i tried to add only 1 view but the result was still same.

Is there a way to do that without lag, i checked twitter, foursquare, pinterest apps, they work smoothly.

Comment: Are you using Titanium Mobile SDK? Please give some details of your implementation!

Comment: Well there are some implementation details that can be improved. waiting 3-4 seconds until scrolling is enabled is too long in my opinion. Be sure that the request is send asynchronous. Unfortunately you're not able to choose a specific thread. titanium does this on its own.